# Which Linux distro resembles HP-UX?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

I'm looking for a Linux distro (or some Unix flavor...) that is similar to HP-UX so that I practice the command line as well as other things. This is in order to get CSA Certification. Which distro should I use? I already know Linux basics.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid no Linux distribution resemble HP-UX (or AIX, Solaris for that matter) enough to be helpful in your case.

While all Unix and Unix like OSes share a similar posix layer, there is a major difference on the system administration side which is what CSA certification is about I presume.

Comment: I'll second this: HP-UX resembles nothing else. It's kind of a dinosaur, in that it still has Bell Labs "make", and other utilities, not BSD or GNU. It has a lot of system admin peculiarities, because HP had a bad, bad case of "Not Invented Here".  It's reminiscent of the old Proprietary Unixes, SunOS, Dynix, Hep/ux,  Mt Xinu, DGUX, etc etc.  Also, the PA-RISC hardware that HP-UX runs on is really odd: it has segments registers, the stack grows up, the heap grows down. Ickk.